# XCode 4.6 breakpoints not working

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

I've just upgraded to XCode 4.6 and iOS 6.1 and breakpoints have stopped working in the simulator (not tested device). Changing debuggers to GDB fixes it but I usually work with LLDB.

Nothing in the project has changed, they just stopped working after the upgrade. I've cleaned and deleted derived data and checked all of the debug settings but nothing is wrong.

Is anyone else getting this?

Max

Comment: i had the same issue only one time and i used to restart the xcode and Mac system and it's solved now and not come again.

Comment: Sadly, a full reset made no difference.

Comment: Changing the debugger from LLDB to GDB in the sceme fixes this for me. LLDB will break in .m or .mm files but not in .cpp files unless I make this change.

Comment: There is a possibility to set breakpoints manually, which seems to work better in some circumstances. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47981640/1617295) for more details

Answer (score 5):

We are experiencing the same problem with our iOS project. This seems to be a new bug in LLDB or XCode 4.6. I just filed a bug report with Apple and would recommend doing the same.

This topic in the Apple Dev forums suggests that the issue might be related to the location of the source files inside the project's directory hierarchy: https://devforums.apple.com/message/754512

Answer (score 0):

I have found that, for us at least, this problem is to do with the way we compile. We use the "unity" theory of compilation where the project is split into sub-projects, each with a single source file that includes all of the other source files. Our issue seems to be that LLDB doesn't break in included cpp files. This is due to how the compiler in-lines files.

The solution is here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/17693317/683614

Answer (score 0):

Dear  please open xcode --> product --> debug --> activate breakpoints.

It will definitely work.

******  ENJOY  *****

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another stupid "user error" is what happened to me - I overrode a method in a category, but continued to put breakpoints on the code that was no longer being called.  Of course it wasn't getting hit. Facepalm!