# XCode doesn't break in #include'd CPP files

Tags: c++, xcode, include, breakpoints

If you include a CPP file from another CPP file, XCode refuses to break at any breakpoints in the included CPP file. I'm going to raise a bug with Apple but just wanted to mention it here in case others have come across this and have maybe found ways around it.

There are very good reasons that you may want to include CPP files from CPP files which I won't go into here. Suffice to say, I can't simple re-arrange the project to compile the included files directly.

Example: A very simple iPhone project

**main.mm**

```
extern void FunctionInSource1( int a );

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FunctionInSource1( 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

**source1.cpp**

```
#include "source2.cpp"

void FunctionInSource1( int a )
{
    int b = a;

    FunctionInSource2( b );

    return;
}
```

**source2.cpp**

```
void FunctionInSource2( int b )
{
    int c = b;

    c = c + 1;

    return;
}
```

main.mm and source1.cpp are members of the target, i.e. they are set to build. source2.cpp is NOT a member of the target and is NOT compiled except through its inclusion in source1.cpp

Setting a breakpoint anywhere in source2.cpp fails to trigger. Breakpoints anywhere else work fine. N.B. You can still step into source2.cpp from source1.cpp for example, just not break directly in source2.cpp

If anyone has come up with a solution I'd be very happy to hear about it.

Max

Comment: And you haven't used optimisation, so that the compiler inlines the whole thing?

Answer (score 14):

Thanks to a reply over on the Apple developer forums I have now solved this problem.

The compiler is in-lining these files and by default LLDB doesn't break on in-lined files. To force it to break you need to add a setting to your .lldbinit file.

Edit (or create) the file **~/.lldbinit** and add the following line:

```
settings set target.inline-breakpoint-strategy always
```

It's as simple as that!

Comment: Wow. Saved the file, ran the project again, breakpoints hit. Thanks!